# Developing with Google Adsense/DFP

Tags: adsense, google-dfp, adsense-api

I'm developing a web app that will use Google Adsense or DFP as a method of monetisation. I've tried searching for some reliable info but I can't find any.

How do I run a development environment with Adsense/DFP so that ads will show, but not create revenue in our account? Obviously if I just put the tag on my site my account will eventually get banned because the traffic isn't legitimate. Is there a Javascript flag I can set in development to show ads but not create revenue?

Similarly, is Adsense/DFP smart enough to ignore requests from a certain location (such as my office) because once the app is deployed to production our team is likely going to need to test/use the app.

Basically I want to do everything I can so our account doesn't get banned.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case if you need it for android app, you are able to define test unit ad (ads:adUnitId="/6499/example/banner") or you can also request test ads by using AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice. 
Maybe, there is also test unit for web app but I didn't manage to find it.

Previously, you were able to mark ad as test on this way **google_adtest = “on”**  but it is seems that it is depricated now.

Take a look at links below for advices how to avoid ban by Google:

[avoid ban](http://www.clickonf5.org/8084/ways-avoid-ban-google-testing-site-adsense-code-localhost/) |
[google adsense preview](http://www.clickonf5.org/5169/tools-preview-google-adsense/)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are developing an website: **There is no supported "dev" version of Adsense**. You can only use it on a live site.

Related

- [How do you render Google ad units in localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54043177/how-do-you-render-google-ad-units-in-localhost)

Source(s)

- https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/3452323
- https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/2034552
- https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/3167312