# How do you render Google ad units in localhost?

Tags: javascript, html, localhost, mamp, adsense

Per research there was a previous question from 2014 ([Is Google adsense available for localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864860/is-google-adsense-available-for-localhost)) that suggested adding:

```
data-adtest="on"
```

and after testing and reading the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864860/is-google-adsense-available-for-localhost#comment93594433_34389120) the solution no longer works. In an ad unit:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- responsive_ad -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
        style="display:block"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-####"
        data-ad-slot="######"
        data-ad-format="auto"
        data-adtest="on"
        data-full-width-responsive="true">
    </ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

After testing in Chrome, Firefox and Safari a white box is rendered. After searching I'm not able to locate any solution in product forums or on any site. How can I test an ad unit in localhost?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also tried the `data-adtest="on"` approach and it didnt work for me either. I found two different approaches for testing:

- Using **Placeholders**, the way most Google Adsense Forum Entry suggesting it.
  e. g. here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/adsense/RLeUEq6na-w/i93-TFVRiHUJ
  (I've tried it on my own and I was satisfied with the solution)
- Use your own **(dev) domain** explained here: https://medium.com/@jeffersonlicet/testing-ads-on-localhost-300215b415d6 (I was not able to tried this on my own, because I dont have a domain)

If you have opened the developer console you would have saw that you got an 403 Error. The reasons for this error are further explained here: https://www.shoutmeloud.com/adsense-403-forbidden-error.html. To make it short: **Adsense Crawlers reject Localhost**. Thats why you got a white space instead of ads.

But if there is a third way I would also be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 3):

I tried many options but they did not work.

I see white screen and 403 error.

I find that workaround "border:1px solid red;" and it works

```
<ins style=".....   border:1px solid red;"></ins>
```

I can see the ads area and I will try production without a border

[image: I can see ads area]

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer suggests, using a hostname other than localhost is important. Using `0.0.0.0` can be a simple option.

Since early 2021 Google appears to require explicit TCF v2.0 consent to load any ads. The following snippet can be included in application code or something like [Violentmonkey](https://violentmonkey.github.io/):

```
window.__tcfapi = (command, parameter, callback) => {
    if (command === 'checkConsent') {
        callback(true);
    }
    if (command === 'addEventListener') {
        callback({eventStatus: 'tcloaded', gdprApplies: false}, true);
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried both switching to `0.0.0.0` ad adding that `__tcfapi` variable, but in 2022 neither seems to make ads appear locally :(

Comment: @machineghost can you provide an example that is not working? Defining the `__tcfapi` variable still works for me.

Comment: It turns out there are so many different causes of this problem that Google made an entire series of pages to troubleshoot it: https://support.google.com/adsense/workflow/10383839?hl=en  (I think mine is that they only approved my account recently, but I won't know until I wait and see, because everything in the site indicates I should be seeing ads already).