# Google Adsense testing ads

Tags: vue.js, adsense

i have to try google ads in my web app (Vue JS), where to put them, size, etc...
I'm new in the Google'Ads world and i don't know how to create fake ads from google
[Adsense](https://www.google.com/adsense) require a working online site for the ads (obviously), but this is for the production time, not for the test
How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you want to test? AdSense doesn't provide test ads at this point as you said. You can add `google-adtest="on"` on the adsense tag. Though it might work only on approved domains. So depending on what you want to test you have some options.

If you want to test sizing of ads (how adsense resizes/adapts ad slot) - you can do something like:

```css
.adsbygoogle {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

And see where ad would be displayed and how big it will be.

If you want to test things like clicks - you won't be able to do it, unfortunately, and have to wait for domain to be approved and start getting real ads.

Also found this question which might help: [How do you render Google ad units in localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54043177/how-do-you-render-google-ad-units-in-localhost)